# Context initialization failed Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have Alfresco Community Edition 5.2.

The project has been cloned from GitHub repository, and after that I cannot run it.

I am getting the following error at catalina.out file:

```
 2023-02-02 13:16:49,623  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01020049 Not all patches could be applied
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:118)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:131)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Feb 02, 2023 1:16:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01020049 Not all patches could be applied
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:118)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:131)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and this one also:

```
 2023-02-02 13:16:48,818  ERROR [admin.patch.PatchExecuter] [localhost-startStop-1] 01020048 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01020047 Bootstrap failed
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap.bootstrap(ImporterBootstrap.java:367)
        at com.prodyna.adama.gas.patch.SiteReloadedPatch.applyInternalImpl(SiteReloadedPatch.java:388)
        at com.prodyna.adama.gas.patch.SiteReloadedPatch.applyInternal(SiteReloadedPatch.java:269)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch$1.execute(AbstractPatch.java:455)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch$1.execute(AbstractPatch.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.applyWithTxns(AbstractPatch.java:462)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.access$0(AbstractPatch.java:442)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch$4.doWork(AbstractPatch.java:620)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch$4.doWork(AbstractPatch.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.apply(AbstractPatch.java:624)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch.apply(AbstractPatch.java:586)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl$PatchWork.applyPatch(PatchServiceImpl.java:564)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl$PatchWork.execute(PatchServiceImpl.java:477)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl.applyPatch(PatchServiceImpl.java:332)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl.applyPatchAndDependencies(PatchServiceImpl.java:309)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchServiceImpl.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchServiceImpl.java:198)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.applyOutstandingPatches(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.applyOutstandingPatches(PatchExecuter.java:83)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:131)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter$1.doWork(PatchExecuter.java:1)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter.onBootstrap(PatchExecuter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.view.ImporterException: Failed to import package at line 487; column 75 due to error: Namespace URI http://www.adama.com/model/adamaStudyNotification/1.0 has not been defined in the Repository dictionary
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.view.ViewParser.parse(ViewParser.java:201)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterComponent.parserImport(ImporterComponent.java:430)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterComponent.importView(ImporterComponent.java:279)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap.doImport(ImporterBootstrap.java:485)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap.access$0(ImporterBootstrap.java:374)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap$1$1.execute(ImporterBootstrap.java:356)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap$1.doWork(ImporterBootstrap.java:360)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.ImporterBootstrap.bootstrap(ImporterBootstrap.java:363)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.view.ImporterException: Namespace URI http://www.adama.com/model/adamaStudyNotification/1.0 has not been defined in the Repository dictionary
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.view.ViewParser.getName(ViewParser.java:995)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.view.ViewParser.processStartElement(ViewParser.java:226)
        at org.alfresco.repo.importer.view.ViewParser.parse(ViewParser.java:183)
        ... 63 more
```

While ago I added new sites to alfresco project, and bootstraped them. But now I do not know what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with customized code:

```
com.prodyna.adama.gas.patch.SiteReloadedPatch.applyInternalImpl
```

is not an official Alfresco patch.

```
Failed to import package at line 487; column 75 due to error: Namespace URI http://www.adama.com/model/adamaStudyNotification/1.0 has not been defined in the Repository dictionary
```

seems to be at least one of your issues: the referenced model `http://www.adama.com/model/adamaStudyNotification/1.0` is not defined. You may have forgotten to deploy a dependent module which contains the model xml?

If your intention is to run Alfresco without that module you would need to deploy at least the document model, otherwise Alfresco will not be able to read the metadata of existing documents having the type or aspects defined in that model.